# How many ways to paint the strip of n cells with m colors

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many ways to paint the strip of n cells with m colors while the color should be different from the colors of neighboring cells?

I know that if the neighboring colors can be same, then there is $\binom{n+m-1}{n}$, but what if the colors should be different?

Comment: If neighboring colors can be the same, why aren't there $m^n$ ways to paint the cells? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first cell can be colored using any of the $m$ colors, the second cell can be colored using $m-1$ colors as can be third, fourth and so on. So the total number of ways to color is $m(m-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Omg I think too much....
Thank you!!!!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to count the choices you have from cell to cell. For the first cell you have $m$ choices, then $m-1$ for the second, then $m-1$ again for the third...